# Цветовая схема кнопки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, button

Помогите сверстать вот такую белую кнопочку:

[image]

Если на неё нажать, то перекинет на определённый сайт.

Я уже сделал жёлтую кнопку "Добавить в discord":

```css
body {
  background-color: #25252e;
  margin: 0;
}

.Lite {
  color: white;
  font-family: Bold;
  font-size: 4px;
}

button[name="run_script"] {
  margin: 90px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #ff9900;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

button[name="run_script"]:hover {
  background: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Lite">
    <center>
      <h1>LiteBot</h1>
    </center>
  </div>
  <center>
    <a href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=897526676408373298&scope=bot%20applications.commands&permissions=8">
      <button type="button" name="run_script">Добавить в discord</button>
    </a>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Теперь мне нужно сделать вот такую же белую, но у меня не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, в чём сложность просто поменять цвет фона кнопки на нужный, но судя по разметке, вопросы только начинаются. Не сто́ит использовать устаревшие теги, а вот относительно новые технологии желательны.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #25252e;
}

.lite {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 6em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font: bold 1rem/1em Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add { background: #f90; color: white; }
.add:hover { background: #f60; }

.adv { background: #fff; color: black; }
.adv:hover { background: #ff6600; color: white; }
```

```html
<h1 class="lite">LiteBot</h1>
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="button add">Добавить в discord</a>
  <button class="button adv">Подробнее</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я просто только начинаю учить html, css